# Calling javascript side from the native java part of a cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

i wrote a simple plugin to handle nfc tags because the chariot nfc cordova plugin didnt suit my needs. 
The problem im facing is all tutorial i've found seem to assume i would be invoking a native method from the javascript side like so:

```
cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {}, "myClass", "myMethod", [data]);
```

the thing is the plugin i wrote does it's magic in the onNewIntent method of the native side when a TAG_DISCOVERED event is detected. This is working as it should, and i get the correct data in adb logCat. The problem is i don't know how to pass the data to the javascript side.

I know I'm supposed to send the pluginResult  like this:

```
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "myData");
result.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
```

But I have no clue about the javascript side since the native side is triggered by the android Intent and not my client side. Im a newbie when it comes to androids lifecycle and thus quite confused. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you call from RandomBlob.java this function:

```
callbackContext.success(result);
```

It will call the following function inside your .js file, typically in Cordova, its inside deviceready. The function should be as:

```
var app = {
initialize: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},
onDeviceReady: function () {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    function success(value) {
        var result = value['result'];
        var arg1 = value['arg1'];
        var arg2 = value['arg2'];
        console.log("Cordova.Exec called to multiply " + arg1 + " & " + arg2 + " which resulted in " + result);
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        Cordova.exec(success, null, "RandomBlob", "performMultiply", [500, 3]);
    }, 10000);
}
};
app.initialize();
```

Hope this helps!